# Deploy Spring + Hibernate + Maven + Google Cloud SQL application in Google App Engine

Tags: spring, hibernate, google-app-engine, maven, google-cloud-sql

I have a web application with the Spring+ Hibernate + Maven configuration which is using the Google cloud SQL as database. But I cannt deploy the application successfully in Google App Engine. Please give me a suggestion. Will Google App Engine support my application configuration?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done and here is [the proof of concept](http://blog.essaytagger.com/2011/11/spring-hibernate-on-google-app-engines.html).

Also note that Google App Engine supports only JPA 1.0. Current version of Hibernate 4.0 supports JPA 2.1. It means that its not fully supported by Google App Engine.

Comment: We are using hibernate 3.2. Is it possible to deploy Google App Engine? Can you post a sample configuaration?

Comment: colud you please reply

Comment: You can check this library for using hibernate on GAE http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-gae/

Comment: thanks for your reply.. I found this one. that why my doubt arisen.. This is less descriptive. Even no examples. Can you help more on this is there any links more helpful?